# Alembic: 'relation "public.alembic_version" does not exist' when using `version_table_schema`

Tags: postgresql, python-3.5, alembic

I'm writing some custom code for Alembic to keep my database always updated in my dev environment for a project. The project involves a database with the following:

- A `public` schema for shared data
- A single schema per client "database"
- One schema that acts as a `prototype` for all of the client schemas (orgs)

At this moment, I'm not worried about the multiple client schemas, only keeping the `public` and `prototype` schemas up-to-date. My env.py script works great for the `public` schema, but not `prototype` because alembic is trying to use the version table from `public` when working with `prototype`.

So, I thought I could use the [`version_table_schema`](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=version_table_schema#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.version_table_schema) option to maintain one version table in the `public` schema and one in the `prototype` schema. However, as soon as I start using that, I get a '*relation "public.alembic_version" does not exist*' error when I attempt to do the upgrade.

The only difference that I see is that, when I use `version_table_schema` set to the appropriate schema, the generated revision scripts actually contain a line to `op.drop_table('alembic_version')`. The line ONLY exists when `version_table_schema` is in use.

I'm hoping that I'm just missing something minor.

The following are all of the relevant source files for reference. The only external dependency should be the `appcontext` and `getDeclarativeBase`. `appcontext` is just for configuration and is definitely working (The database connection works properly). `getDeclarativeBase` is a way to dynamically get a declarative base (and related metadata) for a schema. Based on the debug output, that seems to be working correctly as well. The metadata objects themselves are associated with the correct schemas when they are constructed.

---

**Wrapper functions for running migrations.** `autoMigratePublic()` and `autoMigrateOrgProto()` are the problematic methods in this case

```
""" A wrapper around Alembic that will assist with database migrations.

    Our database system is soemwhat complex to upgrade. There is a public
    schema which we use for shared things (such as authentication and job
    management). Then there is the org prototype.

    There are also individual schemas for each client org. These are trickier.

    http://stackoverflow.com/a/35211383/703040

    Also useful:

    https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/0e3319bb36f1612e41a8d7da5a48ce1ca33a0b2b/alembic/config.py#L476
"""

import logging
import os
import time

import alembic.config
import alembic.util

CONFIG_ORG_PROTO = os.path.join("migrations", "alembic_orgproto.ini")
CONFIG_PUBLIC = os.path.join("migrations", "alembic_public.ini")

log = logging.getLogger("sys.migrations")

def autoMigratePublic():
    try:
        freezePublic()
    except alembic.util.CommandError:
        log.warn("[public] Problem creating migration revision. Skipping as this sometimes just means that we are working with a new DB.")
    upgradePublic()
    return

def autoMigrateOrgProto():
    try:
        freezeOrgProto()
    except alembic.util.CommandError:
        log.warn("[orgproto] Problem creating migration revision. Skipping as this sometimes just means that we are working with a new DB.")
    upgradeOrgProto()
    return

def freezePublic():
    log.info("[public] Checking the database for revisions...")
    alembicArgs = [
        "--config", CONFIG_PUBLIC,
        "--raiseerr",
        "revision",
        "--autogenerate",
        "--message", "autogenerate {0}".format(makeRevisionName()),
    ]
    runAlembic(alembicArgs)
    return

def freezeOrgProto():
    log.info("[orgproto] Checking the database for revisions...")
    alembicArgs = [
        "--config", CONFIG_ORG_PROTO,
        "--raiseerr",
        "revision",
        "--autogenerate",
        "--message", "autogenerate {0}".format(makeRevisionName()),
    ]
    runAlembic(alembicArgs)
    return

def makeRevisionName():
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def upgradePublic():
    log.info("[public] Performing database upgrade...")
    alembicArgs = [
        "--config", CONFIG_PUBLIC,
        "--raiseerr",
        "upgrade",
        "head",
    ]
    runAlembic(alembicArgs)
    return

def upgradeOrgProto():
    log.info("[orgproto] Performing database upgrade...")
    alembicArgs = [
        "--config", CONFIG_ORG_PROTO,
        "--raiseerr",
        "upgrade",
        "head",
    ]
    runAlembic(alembicArgs)
    return

def upgradeOrg(schemaName):
    log.info("[%s] Performing database upgrade...", schemaName)
    alembicArgs = [
        "--config", CONFIG_ORG_PROTO,
        "--raiseerr",
        "upgrade",
        "head",
        "-x", "schema={0}".format(schemaName),
    ]
    runAlembic(alembicArgs)
    return

def runAlembic(args):
    return alembic.config.main(args)
```

---

**Class for performing migrations.** This class is referenced in the env.py files

```
import copy
import logging
import os
import re
import traceback

from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import core.context.appcontext
from core.database.declarative import getDeclarativeBase

logging.getLogger("alembic").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#==============================================================================
class Migrator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        from alembic import context
        self.context = context
        self.config = context.config
        self.log = logging.getLogger("sys.migrations")
        self.sys = core.context.appcontext.instance()
        self.schema = self.config.get_main_option("schema")
        if self.context.get_x_argument("schema"):
            self.schema = self.context.get_x_argument("schema")
        return

    def start(self):
        import core.database.tables  # Make sure the metadata is defined
        if self.context.is_offline_mode():
            self.log.error("[%s] Can't run migrations offline", self.schema)
            return
        self.doMigration()
        return

    def doMigration(self):
        targetMetadata = getDeclarativeBase(self.schema).metadata
        engine = create_engine(self.sys.getConnectionUrl(), echo=False)
        self.log.info("[%s] Engine:   %s", self.schema, engine)
        self.log.debug("[%s] Metadata: %s", self.schema, targetMetadata)
        for t in targetMetadata.sorted_tables:
            self.log.debug("    - %s", t)
        conn = engine.connect()
        try:
            self.context.configure(
                conn,
                version_table_schema=self.schema,
                target_metadata=targetMetadata,
                process_revision_directives=self.process_revision_directives,
            )
            with self.context.begin_transaction():
                self.context.run_migrations()
        finally:
            conn.close()
        return

    def process_revision_directives(self, context, revision, directives):
        """ Used to prevent creating empty migrations

            See: http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#don-t-generate-empty-migrations-with-autogenerate
        """
        if self.config.cmd_opts.autogenerate:
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                self.log.debug("[%s] Auto-generated migration is empty. No migration file will be created.", self.schema)
                directives[:] = []
            else:
                self.log.info("[%s] Creating new auto-generated migration revision.", self.schema)
        return
```

---

**Sample `env.py`.** Both the public and prototype upgrades have the same contents

```
from migrations.migrator import Migrator
Migrator().start()
```

---

**Sample config ini** The public and prototype migrations use almost the exact same file

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = migrations/orgproto

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
#truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; this defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat alembic/versions

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = <Not Loaded>

schema = orgproto
```

---

**Mako File** I'm using the default.

```
"""${message}

Revision ID: ${up_revision}
Revises: ${down_revision | comma,n}
Create Date: ${create_date}

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = ${repr(up_revision)}
down_revision = ${repr(down_revision)}
branch_labels = ${repr(branch_labels)}
depends_on = ${repr(depends_on)}

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
${imports if imports else ""}

def upgrade():
    ${upgrades if upgrades else "pass"}


def downgrade():
    ${downgrades if downgrades else "pass"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a response on the [sqlalchemy-alembic google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlalchemy-alembic) that resolved the issue. Posting it here in case it helps anyone else:

> you're likely hitting the very confusing schema rules that apply to 
>   Postgresql.  See 
>   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html#remote-schema-table-introspection-and-postgresql-search-path
>   for details.  Short answer is that schema of "blank" and schema of 
>   "public" are two different things on the Python side, leading to a lot
>   of confusion.
>
> In order to convince autogenerate to not affect alembic_version at all
>   no matter where it pops up, you probably need to create an exclusion 
>   rule using include_object: 
>   http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=include_object#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object
>
> ```
> def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to): 
>     if (type_ == "table" and name == 'alembic_version'): 
>         return False 
>     else: 
>         return True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In our case helped adding of alembic_version into `[alembic:exclude]` section of `migrations/alembic.ini`:

```
[alembic:exclude]
- tables = spatial_ref_sys,topology,layer
+ tables = spatial_ref_sys,topology,layer,alembic_version
```

and next in `migrations/env.py`:

```py
context.configure(
    version_table_schema='public',
    # other params
)
```