# How to run a migration with Python Alembic by code?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to migrate a SQL database using sqlAlchemy and Alembic.
I would like to make simple migration scripts directly in Python code, and not by using Alembic CLI, as described in the docs.

I only found this SO question on this topic: [Using Alembic API from inside application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622170/using-alembic-api-from-inside-application-code/24623004#24623004)

Using this question + Flask-Alembic source code, I tried these simple commands.
engine is linked to my db & metadata contains the information for the migration.

I think I am very close, and the solution should be in one line of code... I'm struggling.

```
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command, autogenerate
from alembic.script import ScriptDirectory
from alembic.runtime.environment import EnvironmentContext

alembic_cfg = Config()
alembic_cfg.set_main_option("script_location", "migrations")
alembic_cfg.set_main_option("url", "postgresql://user:pass@postgres:5432/mydb")

alembic_script = ScriptDirectory.from_config(alembic_cfg)
alembic_env = EnvironmentContext(alembic_cfg, alembic_script)

conn = engine.connect()
alembic_env.configure(connection=conn, target_metadata=metadata)
alembic_context = alembic_env.get_context()
```

I am able to use the following commands to see that it works and detects what fields have to migrate :

```
autogenerate.compare_metadata(alembic_context, metadata)
autogenerate.produce_migrations(alembic_context, metadata)
```

However, I am not able to run the migrations. I tried several commands, and always get an error...

Ex, if I run:

```
with alembic_env.begin_transaction():
    alembic_env.run_migrations()
```

I get :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.pyc in run_migrations(self, **kw)
    301         head_maintainer = HeadMaintainer(self, heads)
    302 
--> 303         for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
    304             with self.begin_transaction(_per_migration=True):
    305                 if self.as_sql and not head_maintainer.heads:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Could anyone help me. I think the solution is a one-liner, but I cannot find how to run the migration on my database...

For information, I have never done any migration on this DB with Alembic, maybe there is the need of an "init" ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):`

Here we shall describe in what order you want to migrate. The sequence consists of steps, each of have `step.migration_fn(**kw)`.

### How to fix

The last step you need is add `_migrations_fn` while you do `alembic_env.configure`.

```
def do_upgrade(revision, context):
    return alembic_script._upgrade_revs(script.get_heads(), revision)

alembic_env.configure(connection=conn, target_metadata=metadata, fn=do_upgrade)
```

`script.get_heads()` returns the last migration. Replace, if you need a specific revision, instead of the last.

Related links:

- [Using Alembic API from inside application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622170/using-alembic-api-from-inside-application-code)

  https://bitbucket.org/davidism/flask-alembic/src/e036f063af1ba667c74560264639a93d812dfd51/flask_alembic/extension.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#extension.py-324