# Python - Packaging Alembic Migrations with Setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, alembic

What is the right way to package Alembic migration files in a Setuptools `setup.py` file? Everything is in my repo root as `alembic/`.

This is a Python application, not a library.

My desired installation flow is that someone can `pip install` the wheel that is my application. They would then be able to initialize the application database by running something like `<app> alembic upgrade --sqlalchemy.url=<db_url>`. Upgrades would then require a `pip install -U`, after which they can run the Alembic command again.

Is this unorthodox?

If not, how would I accomplish this? Certainly a `console_scripts` `entry_points`. But beyond that?

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure this is the right way but I did it this way:

First, you can add sort of custom options to alembic using the -x option and you can find details explained in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622170/using-alembic-api-from-inside-application-code/35211383#35211383). This allows you to specify the `db_url` at runtime and make it override the value in the `config.ini`.

Then I managed to package alembic and my migrations by moving the `alembic.ini` file and the `alembic` directory from my project root to my top-level python package:

```
<project root>
├── src
│   └── <top-level package dir>
│       ├── alembic
│       │   ├── env.py
│       │   ├── README
│       │   ├── script.py.mako
│       │   └── versions
│       │       ├── 58c8dcd5fbdc_revision_1.py
│       │       └── ec385b47da23_revision_2.py
│       ├── alembic.ini
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── <other files and dirs>
└── <other files and dirs>
```

This allows to use the setuptools `package_data` directive inside my `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name=<package_name>,
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_data={
        '<top-level package dir>': ['alembic.ini', 'alembic/*', 'alembic/**/*'],
    },
    [...]
)
```

A this point, the alembic config and revisions are correctly packaged but the `alembic.ini` settings have to be tweaked to reflect the new directory tree. It can be done using the `%(here)s` param which contains the absolute path of the directory containing the `alembic.ini` file:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = %(here)s/alembic

[...]

# version location specification; this defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat alembic/versions
version_locations = %(here)s/alembic/versions

[...]
```

Finally, you have to call `alembic` with the `-c` option which allows to provide the path of the config file:

```
alembic -c <path to alembic.ini> ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there's a way to make the setuptools `'package'` and `'package_data'`kwargs work with a Java/Maven style directory structure, i.e. `./src/main/python/` and `./src/main/db/`?

Comment: Thanks. I'm stuck here wondering how to improve the `alembic -c` part. Because IIUC, the caller will have to write `alembic -c /path/to/virtual/env/.../.../.../top_level_package/alembic.ini`. This is not really satisfying. I'm afraid the only solution to this is to provide an entry point with a script pointing to alembic.ini. But the user doesn't call the alembic exec anymore. It sucks to have to recreate an interface.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this which keeps the main alembic folder along the main package folder is to treat the alembic folder as it's own package to be installed along side your main package.

To do this you must rename it (it can't be called `alembic`, as it will be a top level package, so needs a unique name - I've used `migrations`), and add a `__init__.py` file in the alembic folder and the versions folder.

Running the migrations on deployment requires knowing the path to the installed package - a simple way to do this is to provide a console scripts that applies the migrations.

So the project structure looks like this:

```
<project root>
├── setup.py
├── mypackage
│   └── <project source files...>
│
├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── apply.py
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── README
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── 58c8dcd5fbdc_revision_1.py
│       └── ec385b47da23_revision_2.py
│
└── <other files and dirs>
```

And `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='mypackage',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests',)),
    package_data={'migrations': ['alembic.ini']},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['apply-migrations=migrations.apply:main'],
    },
    install_requires=[
        "SQLAlchemy==1.3.0",
        "alembic==1.0.10",
        # ...
    ]
)
```

And finally `migrations/apply.py`:

```py
# Python script that will apply the migrations up to head
import alembic.config
import os

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

alembic_args = [
    '-c', os.path.join(here, 'alembic.ini'),
    'upgrade', 'head'
]


def main():
    alembic.config.main(argv=alembic_args)
```

Now after installing your wheel, you will have a command `apply-migrations` which you can invoke directly. Note the version I've implemented here doesn't have any arguments - though if you wanted to pass eg. `--sqlalchemy.url` you could add it in `alembic_args`.

Personally I prefer to set the url in `migrations/env.py`. For example if you had an environment variable called `SQLACLHEMYURL` you could add this in `migrations/env.py`:

```py
import os
config.set_main_options(os.getenv('SQLALCHEMYURL'))
```

Then you can invoke:

```
SQLALCHEMYURL=... apply-migrations
```

On deploment.

Comment: this package is squating the `migrations` name, the package should be in `mypackage.migrations` and `entry_point` should be `'apply-migrations=mypackage.migrations:main'`

Comment: After installing the wheel in another package, I have run `apply-migrations` command, I am getting exception like `FAILED: Path doesn't exist: Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.` What's the script_location we need to put in alembic.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

To expose all of `alembic`'s arguments, pass `sys.argv` to alembic. This extends of @Alice Heaton's answer.

Project layout:

```
my-app
├── my_app
│   └── migrations
│       ├── alembic.ini
│       ├── apply.py
│       ├── env.py
│       ├── script.py.mako
│       └── versions
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my-app",
    packages=["my_app"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            # This overwrites the existing alembic command
            "alembic = my_app.migrations.apply:main",
        ],
    },
)
```

`migrations/apply.py`:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import alembic.config

here = Path(__file__).parent


def main():
    argv = [
        # Use our custom config path
        "--config", str(here / "alembic.ini"),
        # Forward all other arguments to alembic as is
        *sys.argv[1:]
    ]
    alembic.config.main(argv=argv)
```

`migrations/alembic.ini`:

```ini
[alembic]
script_location = %(here)s
```