# alembic revision --autogenerate more than one script.py.mako file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have simple case i.e, one database. At times, I want to generate a revision using different script.py.mako file (or different content). Is it possible to support more that one script.py.mako file and specify in command not to use default script.py.mako file? Or any other suggestion to generate a revision but with content other than one in script.py.mako file?

In Normal case, when I run `alembic revision --autogenerate --message "message"` command, this generates a revision based on `script.py.mako` template.

But in some cases I want to use the same command, but with some flag or some indication to generate a revision with different content. And content can be as simple as writing something in database or making an api call.

So how can I use `alembic revision --autogenerate` command to generate revision based on supplied flag?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. It's still not perfectly clear what you are trying to accomplish with your flag/modifier. Can you share specific details – for example, normally, add new columns, tables, etc. But with modifier you want to... _(add columns and tables, but with a prefix?)_

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, though not recommended. Let me explain. The `alembic` CLI is designed to point to an `.ini` file which specifies a configuration, importantly therein, a [`script_location`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/script.html) which points to a directory with migration scripts and a `script.py.mako` file (which generates these migration scripts).

If you want a 2nd but different `script.py.mako` file, you have 2 complicated options (neither of which I recommend):

1. You'll either need to have a separate directory for migrations – which is useful if you have 2 separate databases – but very challenging if you have a single database.
2. You can execute migrations without the CLI and interact with `alembic`'s API directory, as shown here: [Using Alembic API from inside application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622170/) and here: [Rudimental Schema-Level Multi Tenancy for PostgreSQL Databases](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#rudimental-schema-level-multi-tenancy-for-postgresql-databases). ***Be warned***, this is a daunting task in of itself and requires overwriting default alembic configurations, which goes against how the [alembic API is designed](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.run_migrations). It is possible, however, and for advanced users, perhaps preferred.

Instead, I recommend you utilize [conditional migration elements](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#conditional-migration-elements) in your migration script (within `script.py.mako`). This will allow you to perform certain migrations when certain arguments are passed through the CLI.

Lastly, it is possible your question meant to ask how to perform a single migration for a single database within an application which utilizes multiple databases. If this is so, ask an additional Q on SO and tag me in it and I'd be happy to share how to execute that there.

Comment: Thanks Yaakov for quick & useful tips. Appreciated! With your recommended approach the problem is -x flag is available for "alembic -x data=true upgrade head", not for "alembic revision --autogenerate" command. What I am looking for is to generate revision content based on passed argument during autogenerate step. Any idea?

Comment: Certainly doable. Why don't you take a few minutes to update your Q and add very specific details about what you're trying to do. Note, migrations are complex tasks in of themselves, so extra information is going to be super helpful. @anonymousanonymous

Comment: @Yaakov...added more details in question. Thx!

Comment: Hi  @Yaakov Bressler, any idea?

Comment: I moved this thread to the comments in your Q. :) @anonymousanonymous