# Can we execute "alembic upgrade head" command within python program?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

[In this example](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-sqlmodel/)
the command `alembic upgrade head` is ran manually using docker.

My questions are:

- Can this be automated inside a Python project itself?
- How to run this migration in a production environment?

Comment: I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211383/7777016

Comment: Yes this works!!